# What is the relationship between the speed of the end of the thread and the angular velocity of the spool which was pulled by the winding thread?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

On a rough ground, there is a cylindrical spool of inelastic thin thread (as the picture following), the inner and outer radii are $r$ and $R$ respectively, the thin thread is wound in its inner cylinder, its outer cylinder and the ground contact.

Now a force is pulled horizontally on the end of the thread and the thread is tangent to the lower end of the inner cylinder (the thread is always taut!), so that the spool of thread on the ground to do pure rolling (let angular velocity be $\omega$), and at the same time the speed of the end of the thread $v$ is also uniform, seeking the relationship between the speed of the end of the thread and angular velocity of the spool of thread?

[image]

The following image shows a simplified model.
[image]
I have a thought that $v=\omega(R-2r)$, but I'm not sure about its correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Let the centre of the spool have a linear velocity of $u$.

Because the bottom of the spool is not slipping, $u=R\omega$.

Relative to the centre, the point at which the string meets the inner disc has a speed $r\omega$ in the opposite direction to $v$.
Therefore $v=u-r\omega$.

So eliminating $u$ gives $$v=\omega(R-r)$$

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. There are two points at which the string meets the inner disc, one on the string, another on the disc. I don’t think they share the same velocity. If does, the relative velocity between the two points is 0, which mean the length of exposed string remains a constant. It’s impossible provided the two points should slip (don’t satisfy $u=\omega r$).